# Exercise in Cassels's book

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am trying to prove the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $d=q_1q_2$ where $q_1> 0$, $q_2>0$ are rational primes, with $q_1\equiv 2\mod 9$ and $q_2 \equiv 5 \mod 9$. Then the only rational point on
> $$C: X_1^3+X_2^3+dX_3^3=0$$
> is $(1,-1,0)$

I know that that it is enough to prove that the only points on $C$ are those with $x_3=0$, and without loss of generality, we can assume that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are coprime in $\mathbb{Z}$. Now we can write our equation in the form
$$(x_1+x_2)(\rho x_1 +\rho^{-1} x_2)(\rho^{-1} x_1+\rho x_2)=-q_1q_2x_3^3.$$

I prove that there exist $ \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \omega_1,\omega_2, \omega_3$ such that either
$$x_1+x_2=\alpha_1\omega_1^3, \quad \rho x_1 +\rho^{-1} x_2=\alpha_2\omega_2^3 \quad \rho^{-1}x_1+\rho x_2 =\alpha_3\omega_3^3 \quad \alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3=d$$
or
$$x_1+x_2= \lambda \alpha_1\omega_1^3 \quad \rho x_1 +\rho^{-1} x_2=\lambda \alpha_2\omega_2^3 \quad \rho^{-1} x_1+\rho x_2 =\lambda \alpha_3\omega_3^3 \quad \alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3=d$$
where $\lambda =\rho -\rho^{-1},$
which implies that
$$\alpha_1\omega_1^3+\alpha_2\omega_2^3+\alpha_3\omega_3^3= 0 \quad \alpha_1\alpha_2 \alpha_3 =d.$$

Cassels sketched the proof of the theorem; he indicates that any rational $q_1$-adic unit is congruent to a cube modulo $q$, but this does not hold for $\rho$ where $\rho$ is a primitive 3rd root of unity. Can someone help me understanding the last statement ? Thanks

Comment: To me it sounds as if **rational** $q_1$-adic unit means an element in $\mathbb{Z}_{q_1}^{\times}$. Since $3$ does not divide $q_1-1$, all units a cubes modulo $q_1$ there.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich, thanks for your reply, but I did not quite understand, your last statement, Since 3 does not divide $q_1$, all units a cubes modulo $q_1$. Can you please elaborate on this please ? thanks again

Comment: $q_1\not\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ means that the cubing homomorphism $\bigl(\mathbb{Z}/q_1\bigr)^{\times} \to \bigl(\mathbb{Z}/q_1\bigr)^{\times} $ is an isomorphism and so they are all cubes.

Comment: @dina This is basic group theory. In general, if $G$ is a finite abelian group, and $n$ is coprime to the order of $G$, then the $n$-th power map $G\to G$ is an isomorphism. All you need to check is that the kernel of the map is trivial. However, if $g\in G$ satisfies $g^n=1$, then the order of $g$ divides both $n$ and $|G|$, hence the order of $g$ is $1$, i.e., $g=1$.